# Grouping results from for-loop C#

Tags: c#

First time asking a question on Stackoverflow, fingers crossed! I'm new to programming and I'm struggeling to solve an issue. I got this foor loop:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < antal.Count(); i++)
        {
            tbxResultat.AppendText(namnLista.ElementAt(i) + " \t");
            tbxResultat.AppendText(personnummerLista.ElementAt(i).ToString() + " \t");
            tbxResultat.AppendText(distriktLista.ElementAt(i) + " \t");
            tbxResultat.AppendText(antal.ElementAt(i).ToString() + newLine);
        }
```

I want to group the results from the loop into 4 sections: first values 0-49, second 50-99, third 100-199 and fourth 199. I'm interested in seeing how many is in each section and having it printed right each section, like:

```
23  
37
---------------------------------
Total count of 2 in first section.
```

I've tried putting the for-loop in if statments but with no success. The sortment of the list is done with bubble sort which i modified to take a List instead of array. Any tips in the right direction would be much appriciated!
/Drone

Comment: Which of your values should be tested for being in the range 0-49 etc?

Comment: Show us what you tried, it sound like you need it the other way around: inside the `for` test `if (i % 50 == 0) ...`

Comment: OT it looks like you should be using a single list of a new class, instead of 4 separate lists that are "linked" over the index

Comment: What list do we use to group the results? `antal`? It's not clear because the code writes several values, and we see only one in a row in your example.

Comment: Hello, sorry, yes it's antal that should be counted!

Answer (score 0):

This code should be what you asked for. Note the `while` in there. It's not `if` because there may be groups with zero elements, so you have to handle those as well.

```
int groupLimit = 50;
int elementsInGroup = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < antal.Count(); i++, elementsInGroup++)
{
    while (antal[i] >= groupLimit)
    {
        // Write summary here. Use elementsInGroup..

        groupLimit += 50;
        elementsInGroup = 0;
    }

    // Write one row here. I suggest building the string and calling only one AppendText..
}
```

Comment: So I would need to do this for each section? Setting the group limit to the next section etc. Not sure what you mean by "Write summary here"? But I very much appriciate you taking the time! /Drone

Comment: @ggdrone, I assume you want to print a group, then the summary of that group, then the next group and its summary, and so on. If this is not the case then you should add more info to your question. Also, there is no need to add this /Drone signature. We know who you are, and also we don't care ;-)

Comment: I read your answer again and saw the groupLimit += 50 which I missed before, I'll try this solution. Ahh, new to this... :)